# 5 mm 12 V 5 W filament lamp

Tags: identification, lamp, halogen

Please help to identify small filament lamp, size about 5 mm. Voltage specified as 12 V. It was mounted on the IR source.
There is a little vertical metal spring (not filament, another one) inside glass body, it was broken during demounting, you can see it in separate photo.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks like a pretty specialized source bulb, probably best to go at it from the manufacturer angle (Shimadzu or whatever). It isn't something you are going to be able to purchase from an electronics distributor.

Comment: I fail to see the value of a halogen filling at IR temperatures, then again, the bulb *is* blackened.

Comment: That spring is intriguing. For mains voltage compact halogen, there is a fuse in series which I suppose you can make in the shape of a spring but it's normally just a thin metal strip. Here however, it does not seem to have any electrical function. Is it just mechanical to have it push itself into position?

Comment: Broken during demounting. Demounting *what*?

Comment: I mean demounting bulb from its holder. There was soldering.

Comment: Is it just mechanical to have it push itself into position?
It was inside glass body, it is hard to imagine how it should push something.